# Access Remote IBM MQ Server Queue using MQ Client through a java program

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I am relatively new to IBM MQ.

My requirement is to connect to a Remote IBM MQ Server Queue through IBM MQ Client. And then, access the queue through MQ Client using IBM MQ Java API.

Is this the right approach?

I have already setup IBM MQ Server, IBM MQ Explorer on my local machine, created a Queue Manager, Queue. I have also written a Java program to connect to MQ using IBM MQ API.

This Java program has the following parameters:

```
String queueManagerName = "QUEUE.MANAGER.1";
String userID = "";
String password = "";
String queueName = "QUEUE1";
String hostName = "localhost";
String channel = "CHANNEL1";
int port = 1414;
```

Here, everything seems to work fine. I can send/receive messages from/to the MQ Server Queue through the Java program.

Now, I have installed IBM MQ Client on the same machine, how do I connect to the same Server Queue using the java program through the MQ Client?

### My requirement is to have:

1. MQ Server running on a different machine.
2. Connect to the Server Queue using the MQ Client installed on local machine.
3. The java program should Send/Receive messages to the Server Queue through the local MQ Client.

How, can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to point connection parameters for your application to connect to queue manager on remote machine. For example:

```
String queueManagerName = "<Remote queue manager name>";
String userID = "<valid user existing on remote machine>";
String password = "<password for user>";
String hostName = "<remote host name>";
String channel = "<Channel name on remote queue manager>";
int port = <port number where queue manager is listening>;
```

But you will need to configure authentication and authorization on remote queue manager for application to connect. If that is not configured, then you will get MQRC 2035 - NOT_AUTHORIZED errors.

Comment: Thanks. That was pretty quick!

Will try the solution.

Comment: But then where would I specify the MQ Client details? My java program should have the details for that right?

Comment: You have to put MQ Jars in class path.

Comment: i am also having same requirement but i have to connect to the client queue with out specifing <remote host name>

Answer (score 0):

```
String mqHost = null; // Hostname
String mqPort = null; // Port
String mqChannel = null; // Channel 
String mqQMgr = null;   // Queue Manager
MQQueueManager qMgr = null;
MQEnvironment.hostname = mqHost;
MQEnvironment.port = Integer.valueOf(mqPort).intValue();
MQEnvironment.channel = mqChannel;
MQEnvironment.properties.put(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES);
MQEnvironment.userID = "USERID";
```

Comment: please provide explanation as to what was wrong and how your answer helps.

Comment: You need to access the Queue Manager with the `qMgr = new MQQueueManager(mqQMgr);`